# Matplotlib set legend labels for double axis plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have produced a bar + lines plot using the following sort of code:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib
import numpy as np
import random
%matplotlib inline

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(20, 5)), columns=list('ABCDE'))


ax = df[['E']].plot(
    secondary_y = True,
    x=df.A,
    kind='bar',

)

ax.legend(['EE'])

df[['A','B','C','D']].plot(
    linestyle='-',
    marker='o',
    ax=ax    
)
ax.legend(['AA','BB','CC','DD'])
ax.autoscale(enable=True, axis='both', tight=False)
```

I would like to change the legend entries for each of the series on the plot (e.g. to `AA` instead of `A` and so on), but I'm struggling to work out how to do this. Can anyone help?

I tried running ImportanceOfBeingErnest's code using matplotlib 2.0.2 and got the following error, but after upgrading to 2.1 it works.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-c26e970bbe42> in <module>()
     10 
     11 ax.figure.legend(['AA','BB','CC','DD'], 
---> 12                  bbox_to_anchor=(1.,1),loc=1, bbox_transform=ax.transAxes)
     13 ax.autoscale(enable=True, axis='both', tight=False)
     14 plt.show()

TypeError: legend() missing 1 required positional argument: 'labels'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works with matplotlib 2.1 or higher.

You could add a figure legend, which will take into account all the artists from all figures. Then setting `legend=False` to the individual pandas plots, and creating one legend in the end would probably give you what you want.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
#%matplotlib inline

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(20, 5)), columns=list('ABCDE'))

ax = df[['E']].plot( secondary_y = True,  x=df.A, kind='bar', legend=False)
ax = df[['A','B','C','D']].plot(  linestyle='-', marker='o',legend=False, ax=ax)

ax.figure.legend(['AA','BB','CC','DD'], 
                 bbox_to_anchor=(1.,1),loc=1, bbox_transform=ax.transAxes)
ax.autoscale(enable=True, axis='both', tight=False)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I tried running your code but I got an error and no plot was produced. I've updated the question to include the error details.

Comment: Sorry for that, you are probably using an older version of matplotlib below 2.1, in which case this solution does not work.

Comment: I'm currently on 2.0.2. I'll try updating.